# Calling a function in the .aspx.cs code behind file with jQuery load()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, code-behind

So I have something like this situation:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-link]', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        url = $this.data('link');
        $("#imagePreview").load("imageProcess.aspx?" + url);
```

where url holds `GET` parameters.  But `imageProcess.aspx` is different than the file I'm in (`dashboard.aspx`) and I need to reference some panels within my `dashboard.aspx` file.  So my question is, using the .load() function, or even any function that could get the job done, how do I call a function, with `GET` parameters, in the `dashboard.aspx` code behind file? I'm fairly new to the `.NET` framework so I apologize if the question sounds elementary.

Comment: [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods » Encosia](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `imageProcess.aspx.cs` create a webmethod like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string YourMethod(your parameters)
{
//Do Your Work
}
```

and in your dashboard page, in javascript use jquery to send request your webmethod like:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: "imageProcess.aspx/YourMethod",
    data: "{parameter1Name:'" + JSON.stringify(parameter1value) + "', Parameter2Name:'" + JSON.stringify(parmeter2Value) + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
// do your success work, keep in mind that your returned data will be in data.d
    },
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
// do your failuer work
}
});
```

I hope it will give you a guidance to achieve your task.

Comment: Thank you! so just to clarify, doing this I can have access to my `asp:panels` from my `dashboard.aspx` page?

Comment: If you mean to say that panels are on dashboard.aspx and you want to access them in javascript on dashboard.aspx, i will say yes you can access them.

Comment: I mean that I want to access them in the imageProcess.aspx code behind, because I need to append html code to them that I generate server-side.

Comment: You won't be able to access them over in imageProcess.aspx, however from above method you can return the data or html and append that while staying in Dashboard.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure: You are trying to access functionality from a different aspx page than the one you are currently on.
I'm not entirely sure if you can do that the easy way by java script. Maybe someone else knows a better way, but the way I would do it is creating ashx service page which will handle your request so you can provide the data you need (in your case an image)

For more information see http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Comment: Well currently I'm calling a different aspx page, but I want to call a function in the _current_ aspx.cs page, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well then I think this is what you are looking for:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109